# How to choose the file type in FluentFTP?

Tags: c#

When I download a certain file from the FTP, it comes desconfigurated. It is a report in .txt 200mb over 2 million rows from a ERP System

With the WinSCP, I choose the option to download as TEXT, the only way it downloads right. Downloading without this option (as normal) it happens the same as downloading with the FluentFTP using DownloadFile().

Is it possible to choose the file type with the FluentFTP?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FtpConfig.DownloadDataType` property](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/wiki/File-Transfer):

```
var config = new FtpConfig() { DownloadDataType = FtpDataType.ASCII };
var client = new FtpClient(host, user, pass, config);
client.DownloadFile(localPath, remotePath);
```